# Adding borders on collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift

Everytime a user click on a specific cell, the cell will have a border. The problem is when I scroll back and forth, the border is selecting random cell to have a border.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
```

just in case you're looking for the didDeselect part

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add a border to an only selected cell?

Comment: yes, only to the selected cell. And also get rid of adding border on random cells

Comment: to those who downvoted this, speak up. why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because reusability of cells. You should take property in your cell model to track selected status - `isSelected: Bool`

Now in `cellForItem` method, you have to put if else and make your cell bordered if `isSelected` is `true`.

Here note that, don't forgot to put else part and remove border in else part.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell?.isSelected = true
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell?.isSelected = false
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        ...
        ...
        if cell.isSelected {
            //put border logic
        }else {
            // remove border
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add border easily to selectedCell using "selectedRow".

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var selectedRow = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if selectedRow == indexPath.row {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        }
        else {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedRow == indexPath.row {
           selectedRow = -1
        } else {
            selectedRow = indexPath.row
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this my Way:

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath{
    didSet{
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var borderColor: CGColor! = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0

        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath{
            borderColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor
            borderWidth = 1 //or whatever you please
        }else{
            borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            borderWidth = 0
        }

        cell.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth //You can use your component
        cell.layer.borderColor = borderColor 

   }
```

Comment: collectionView.reloadData() will always be called everytime selectedIndexPath changes the value right?

Comment: Yes it would be reflected on each click @jay123456

Answer (score 0):

Because of cell re-use, you are currently facing this issue. To solve this:

When you select a cell (in `didSelectItemAt`), save the `indexPath.row` in local variable. In `cellForRow` method, put check like: if indexPath.row==savedValue, then borderColor will be blue, else normal color.