# Change UICollectionView cell color onTap

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am just a beginner in swift.
I am using UICollectionView for displaying options of a quiz. All I want is to change the border color of the selected cell (option) when user tap on that. Also, there should be some timeout like of 1 second so that user can see if his option is correct (green color) or incorrect (red color)

how can I do that?

I tried changing `layer.borderColor` in `didSelectItemAt` function but that doesn't work

here's sample code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let cell = optionCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
  cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2
  if isCorrect{
     cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
  }
  else{
     cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
 }

}
```

Comment: did you also give layer a desired width ?

Comment: @user3344236 yes edited my question with sample code.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935711/adding-borders-on-collectionview-cell